# Transaction using Metamask works. Fails with web3.py

Tags: transactions, etherscan, web3.py, error

I have two transaction, the first from MetaMask (everything is fine)

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1ab684f4875f8cc28043d9f3c3536a5e4f8a565cadda7a29bc6a96db5f1d0f8f

the second using web3.py (it seems to be identical but fails)

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc019007895cb7340f65c3bd80df5561c1b1a98d8eac6dc2babf776ab000de067

Here is my part of the code: (I hope it is clear what is going on - it is copied from a class)

```
# same as in the working one
abidata = '0x338b5dea000000000000000000000000e41d2489571d322189246dafa5ebde1f4699f49800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002d79883d2000'
trans = {
                        'to': self.address,
                        'from': self.ethapi.address,
                        'data': abidata,
                        'value': 0,
                        'chainId': 1}
# transaction gas data [pseudocode]
trans_new = trans.copy()
nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(self.address)
gas_price = self.get_gas_price()
gas_price_wei = self.w3.toWei(gas_price,"Gwei")
trans_new["gas"] = 250000
trans_new["nonce"] = nonce
trans_new["gasPrice"] = gas_price_wei
signed_transaction = account.signTransaction(trans)
w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_transaction.rawTransaction)
```

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: From the vmtrace it is failing in the token contract. Did you call `approve()` to allow ED to make a transfer from your address?

Comment: Actually not. I approved to https://radarrelay.com/. Was playing around. Maybe that is the reason. It's just strange that it seems to work with MetaMask, so I guess there is some kind of difference in both transactions.

Comment: I removed the approve but still getting the same message: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb11dfab88c768433fb5639632579c8f62bc5f56330325d22753b19a54957fd97

Comment: You need to send ZrxToken an approval for EtherDelta to make a transfer from your account. If you want to make a deposit to EtherDelta you need to make two transactions 1) `ZrxToken.approve(EtherDelta.address, amount, { from: "YourAccount" })`, 2) `EtherDelta.depositToken(ZrxToken.address, amount, { from: "YourAccount" })`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it out and post! Its just strange that with MetaMask I see only one transaction that was send from my account.

Comment: That solved it!!! Thanks a lot again. I have missed that MetaMask did two transactions. It works really well!

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Ismael in the comments above, my mistake was that MetaMask did two transactions. So the first one was an approval that was missing.